# Camera speed dependent on 3D scene extents

Tags: performance, 3d, camera

I'm working on a 3D scene viewer with the [HOOPS Engine](http://www.techsoft3d.com/)

I want to implement support for a 3D mouse. Everything is working fine but there is one remaining problem I don't know how to solve:

I move my camera with following formula:

`HC_Dolly_Camera(-(factor.x * this->m_speed), factor.y * this->m_speed, factor.z * this->m_speed);`

this->m_speed is dependent on scene extents. But if the scene is really big (e.g. a airport) the camera speed is on a deep zoom level ridiculous fast.

My first attempt was to implement a kind of damping factor which is dependent on the distance from objects to my camera. It works ... somehow. Sometimes I noticed ugly "bouncing effects" which I can avoid with smooth acceleration and a modified cosine function.

But my question is: Is there a best practice to reduce camera speed in closeup situations in a 3D scene? My approach is working, but I think it is not a good solution due it uses many raycasts.

Best regards,
peekaboo777

P.S.:

My code

```
if(!this->smooth_damping)
{
    if(int res = HC_Compute_Selection_By_Area(this->view->GetDriverPath(), ".", "v", -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5) > 0)
    {
        float window_x, window_y, window_z, camera_x, camera_y, camera_z;

        double dist_length = 0;
        double shortest_dist = this->max_world_extent;

        while(HC_Find_Related_Selection()) 
        {
            HC_Show_Selection_Position(&window_x, &window_y, &window_z, &camera_x, &camera_y, &camera_z);
            this->view->GetCamera(&this->cam);

            // Compute distance vector
            this->dist.Set(cam.position.x - camera_x, cam.position.y - camera_y, cam.position.z - camera_z);
            dist_length = sqrt(pow((cam.position.x - camera_x), 2) + pow((cam.position.y - camera_y), 2) + pow((cam.position.z - camera_z), 2));

            if(dist_length < shortest_dist)
                shortest_dist = dist_length;
        }
        // Reduced computation

        // Compute damping factor
        damping_factor = ((1 - 8) / (this->max_world_extent - 1)) * (shortest_dist - 1) + 8;

        // Difference to big? (Gap)
        if(qFabs(damping_factor - damping_factor * 0.7) < qFabs(damping_factor - this->last_damping_factor))
        {
            this->smooth_damping = true;
            this->damping_factor_to_reach = damping_factor; // this is the new damping factor we have to reach
            this->freezed_damping_factor = this->last_damping_factor; // damping factor before gap.

            if(this->last_damping_factor > damping_factor) // Negative acceleration
            {
                this->acceleration = false;
            }
            else // Acceleration
            {
                this->acceleration = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this->last_damping_factor = damping_factor;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if(this->acceleration)
    {
        if(this->freezed_damping_factor -= 0.2 >= 1);

        damping_factor = this->freezed_damping_factor + 
                         (((this->damping_factor_to_reach - this->freezed_damping_factor) / 2) - 
                         ((this->damping_factor_to_reach - this->freezed_damping_factor) / 2) * 
                         qCos(M_PI * this->damping_step)); // cosine function between freezed and to reach

        this->last_damping_factor = damping_factor;

        if(damping_factor >= this->damping_factor_to_reach)
        {
            this->smooth_damping = false;
            this->damping_step = 0;
            this->freezed_damping_factor = 0;
        } // Reset
    }
    else
    {
        if(this->freezed_damping_factor += 0.2 >= 1);

        damping_factor = this->damping_factor_to_reach + 
                         ((this->freezed_damping_factor - this->damping_factor_to_reach) - 
                         (((this->freezed_damping_factor - this->damping_factor_to_reach) / 2) - 
                         ((this->freezed_damping_factor - this->damping_factor_to_reach) / 2) * 
                         qCos(M_PI * this->damping_step))); // cosine functio between to reach and freezed

        this->last_damping_factor = damping_factor;

        if(damping_factor <= this->damping_factor_to_reach)
        {
            this->smooth_damping = false;
            this->damping_step = 0;
            this->freezed_damping_factor = 0;
        } // Reset
    }

    this->damping_step += 0.01; // Increase the "X"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the HOOPS engine, but do you have any way to get the closest object to the camera? You could scale your speed with this value, so your camera gets slower close to objects.

Even better would be to take the closest point on bounding-box instead of center of object. This would improve the behaviour close to big objects like long walls/floor.

Another solution I'd try would be to raycast through the view center to look for the first object and use the distance the same way. In this approach you'll not be slowed down by objects behind you. You may also add additional raycast points, like in 1/4 of screen and blend resulting values, so you have more constant speed scale.

What I understand from your question is that you want a way to steer camera through large scenes, like an airport and still be able to move slowly close to the objects. I don't think there's some 'universal' way of doing it. All will depend on your Engine/API features and specific needs. If all those solutions doesn't work, maybe you should try with paper and pen ;) .

Comment: In my actual approach I use a lot of raycasts to determine the distance to the objects in front of my camera. I pick up the closest point to my camera und reduce the moving speed with a cosine function. It's working but if you move left for example and a object comes into your field of view the camera speed gets very low. It's smooth bit it doesn't feel naturally. I will try to implement additional raycast points and post my result here

Answer (score 0):

You said that m_speed is dependent on scene extent, I guess this dependency is linear (by linear I mean if you are measuring the scene extend with something called sExtent, m_speed equals c*sExtent that c is some constant coefficient).

So to make m_speed dependent on scene extent but avoid huge m_speed for large scale scenes , I suggest to make dependency of m_speed to sExtent non-linear, like logarithmic dependency:

```
m_speed = c*log(sExtent+1)
```

This way your m_speed will be bigger if scene is bigger, but not in the same ratio. you also can use radical to create non-linear dependency. below you can compare these functions:

[image]